# Which provision of the law allows the President to discharge student debt?

Tags: united-states, us-president

President Biden recently announced that student debt will be forgiven for some groups of Americans but I couldn't figure out which provision of the law allows Biden to do this without a bill passed by Congress?

Comment: Explain the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I will note that Googling "biden student loan forgiveness legal theory" returns several results describing the theory I described below.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I tried to Google "biden student loan law provision" and came up with nothing.

Comment: I don't have time to provide a full answer but it appears that this happens all the time. https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2022/08/biden-student-debt-relief-legal-supreme-court.html "The federal government forgives student loans all the time. Multiple statutes give the Department of Education sweeping authority to cancel loans for a broad range of reasons. Before Wednesday, the administration had already approved $32 billion in student loan relief for more than 1.6 million borrowers.*"

Comment: @JoeW yeah, sadly it seems like the law was written to allow for massive moral hazard...

Comment: @JonathanReez I am not sure I consider letting people get out of massive amounts of student debt is a moral hazard. There is a reason that it is considered important for people to get a college education and we shouldn't have people not getting one because of the expense or have them not contributing to the economy as a whole because all they can afford is to pay off student loans.

Comment: @JoeW the moral hazard is in the fact that colleges are now encouraged to further jack up their costs while students are encouraged to ignore these high costs because the government will forgive it all anyway. I wouldn't have a problem with Biden's decision if forgiving the loans meant that the colleges would lose all the money that was forgiven. Most European colleges somehow provide education of similar quality for far lower costs.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am not sure I agree with that as they are already jacking up the rates they are charging people because of the fact that the loans are almost impossible to default on through bankruptcy. The small amount that is being forgiven here isn't going to have much of an impact on anything and as I pointed out much more has been forgiven already and no one is really talking about it.

Comment: @JoeW you're right, all loan discharges are highly problematic as they prevent the free market from functioning properly and fail to incentivize students to choose the cheaper colleges. And the Feds could stop the ballooning of costs almost immediately by putting a hard cap on the yearly cost of college education that can be subsidized by government loans. Biden doesn't even need Congress to enact this reform tomorrow. I fail to see why taxpayers should be funding bloated admin salaries and sports stadiums.

Comment: @JonathanReez Or you can say not letting people discharge loans means that the lenders  are able to charge as much as they want and make as many bad loans as they can without any worry that they will ever lose money on this. It shouldn't be a matter of students choosing a cheaper college but not allowing colleges to charge an outrageous cost that puts people in so much debt it prevents them from participating in the economy.  How many highly skilled fields do we have a shortage in because the cost of schooling is so expensive yet the earnings in the field make it impossible to pay back loans

Comment: I fail to see the reasons why colleges (upper admin) and student loan services should be making so much money on services that are critical for our country to compete in the international market place.

Comment: @JoeW you are right, prevention of moral hazard should go both ways. Colleges shouldn't be allowed to benefit from government-sponsored loans if they charge too much money or fail to produce high-income graduates (see "income sharing agreements" for a great counter-example). Meanwhile students shouldn't ever think that their loan would be forgiven. Both colleges and students need to have as much skin in the game as possible, with no recourse to Uncle Sam.

Comment: I fail to see why the students getting the loans should be at blame when the lenders know that there will be serious issues getting repayment and have actually fought to ensure that student loans are one of the few types of loans can't be discharged by bankruptcy. Very few people get student loans with the knowledge that they will not be able to repay them and it will end up costing them for a very long time. The lending institutes however have that knowledge and because they keep giving the loans the colleges can keep charging the high rates.

Comment: @JoeW you are right and ideally bankruptcy *should* discharge student loans, with the college losing money if this happens. But the Feds should also stop giving money to colleges that charge too much money for too little results. The free market should be allowed to reign supreme. If at least a few colleges are not going bankrupt and shutting down every year due to losing in the free market, you know something is wrong.

Answer (score 12):

The most prominent argument that has been advanced surrounding this proposed action can be summarized as follows:  There *was* a bill passed by Congress, in 1965, that authorizes the Secretary of Education to take this action.

This theory holds that the executive branch was granted the authority to cancel federal student loan debt as part of the Higher Education Act, duly passed by Congress in 1965 (and encoded as USC 20 §1001 *et seq.*)  Specifically, [§1087hh](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/20/1087hh) states that:

> In carrying out the provisions of this part, the Secretary is authorized—
>
> 1. to consent to modification, with respect to rate of interest, time of payment of any installment of principal and interest or any portion thereof, or any other provision of any note evidencing a loan which has been made under this part;
> 2. to enforce, pay, compromise, **waive, or release any right, title, claim, lien, or demand, however acquired, including any equity or any right of redemption;** ...

Further background on the legal theory under which this authorizes debt cancellation can be found in [this memo from the Project on Predatory Student Lending](https://static.politico.com/4c/c4/dfaddbb94fd684ccfa99e34bc080/student-debt-letter-2.pdf.pdf), sent to Sen. Elizabeth Warren during her 2020 presidential campaign.  They concluded that via this language,

> Congress has granted the Secretary [of Education] a more specific and unrestricted authority to create and to cancel or modify debt owed under federal student loan programs in the Higher Education Act (HEA) itself. That provision empowers the Secretary to execute the broad debt cancellation plan you have proposed.

It should be noted that this argument is not universally accepted.  It should also be noted that [it is questionable whether anyone could have standing to challenge this action,](https://www.virginialawreview.org/articles/standing-and-student-loan-cancellation/) so whether or not it is allowable may not be testable in court.  And finally, it is not yet clear (at least not to me) what the details of this particular executive action are;  I'm not even sure they have been released.  It could be that they're based on an entirely different legal theory.

Answer (score -1):

The president can't do anything related to money unless a bill is passed by Congress. [Here is one bill](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/20/1082) that was already passed by Congress (20 USC 1082(a)(6)), which bears a relationship to student loans. There are other bills passed by Congress, such as [Higher Education Relief Opportunities for Students act 2003](https://www.congress.gov/bill/108th-congress/house-bill/1412). When the order is eventually made available, we may be able to comment on the proposed application of the law.

Comment: "The president can't do anything related to money unless a bill is passed by Congress." This is a bit over broad. Appropriations need to be approved by Congress, but not necessary "anything related to money".